# How to write from a text files to one xml

Tags: java, xml, parsing, text

I will like to write a number of text files into one xml file. Below are three sample datasets

data1.txt

```
 Name    Score
 Leslie  25
 Pat     12
 Alfred  32
```

data2.txt

```
Name    Score
Leslie  35
Keith   22
Alfred  12
```

data3.txt

```
Name    Score
Philip  38
Keith   32
Diop    22
```

The code used to do this work is as follows:

```
public class Modify {
public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException {
    List<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> score = new ArrayList<String>();


    String path = "C:/Users/yawa/Desktop/INRIX Database/InrixDataProc/question/";

    String textfile;
    // reading data 
    File folder = new File(path);

    File [] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(new FilenameFilter(){

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File folder, String name){
            return name.endsWith(".txt");               
        }
    });

    for (int ixa=0; ixa<listOfFiles.length; ixa++){

        textfile = listOfFiles[ixa].getName();
         String inputfile = textfile;

         FileReader fr1 = new FileReader(inputfile);
         BufferedReader bfr1 = new BufferedReader(fr1);
         String aLine1;
         while ((aLine1 = bfr1.readLine()) != null) {
             String[] split = aLine1.split("\t");
             name.add(split[0]); score.add(split[1]);

         }
    bfr1.close();
 // writing data to xml       
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
    try{
        dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.newDocument();
         Element rootElement =doc.createElementNS("http://www.journaldev.com/employee", "Employees");

         doc.appendChild(rootElement);
         for (int ix=1; ix<name.size(); ix++){
             rootElement.appendChild(getEmployee(doc,name.get(ix),score.get(ix)));
         }

         TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
         Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
         //for pretty print
         transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
         DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

         StreamResult console = new StreamResult(System.out);
         StreamResult filexx = new StreamResult(new File("C:/Users/yawa/Desktop/INRIX Database/InrixDataProc/brxxx.xml"));

         //write data
         transformer.transform(source, console);
         transformer.transform(source, filexx);


    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    }
}

private static Node getEmployee(Document doc, String id, String score){
    Element employee = doc.createElement("Employee");
    employee.setAttribute("id", id);
    employee.appendChild(getEmployeeElements(doc,employee,"score", score));
    return employee;
}

private static Node getEmployeeElements (Document doc, Element element, String name,String value){
    Element node = doc.createElement(name);
    node.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(value));
    return node;    
}
```

}

Current Results

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<Employees xmlns="http://www.journaldev.com/employee">
-<Employee id="Leslie">
<score>25</score>
</Employee>
-<Employee id="Pat">
<score>12</score>
</Employee>
-<Employee id="Alfred">
<score>32</score>
</Employee>
-<Employee id="Name">
 <score>Score</score>
 </Employee>
 -<Employee id="Leslie">
 <score>35</score>
 </Employee>
 -<Employee id="Keith">
 <score>22</score>
 </Employee>
 -<Employee id="Alfred">
 <score>12</score>
 </Employee>
 -<Employee id="Name">
 <score>Score</score>
 </Employee>
 -<Employee id="Philip">
 <score>38</score>
 </Employee>
 -<Employee id="Keith">
 <score>32</score>
 </Employee>
 -<Employee id="Diop">
 <score>22</score>
 </Employee>
 </Employees>
```

I want to replace the Employee id if it already exist in the xml file. At the same time, I want to be able to add new employees. The current code cannot replace existing entries

Answer (score 0):

```
private static Node getEmployeeById(Document doc, String id) {
    if (doc == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("doc must not be null");
    }
    if (id == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("id must not be null");
    }

    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    String path = "//Employee[@id = '" + id + "']";

    try {
        NodeList nl = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(path, doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        return nl.getLength() > 0 ? nl.item(0) : null;
    } catch (XPathExpressionException ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm sure you can figure out the rest.